# AWS Java delete snapshot created with CreateImage

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have used the Java API for AWS for some time now but somehow I can't find how to delete a snapshot that was created with a CreateImage request.

This request will provide you with an Image containing an Image ID.
When you want to remove the image you can Deregister it given this ID.
But I can't find how to delete the snapshot that is being used by that Image.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance,

Giriel

PS: Some code to show what I mean:

```
final CreateImageResult createAMIResult =  AWS.ec2.createImage(new CreateImageRequest().withInstanceId(instanceID).withName(amiName).withNoReboot(noReboot));
final String imageId = createAMIResult.getImageId();

//After a while I want to remove it again

AWS.ec2.deregisterImage(new DeregisterImageRequest(imageId));
//TODO: How to remove the snapshot??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having searched through the AWS Developer forums I found the solution to be quite disappointing.

You have to check the description of all your snapshots and delete the one that matches your image id.

The description has the following format when using CreateImage:
`Created by CreateImage(i-xxxxxxxx) for ami-xxxxxxxx from vol-xxxxxxxx`

So it is a matter of matching the ami-xxxxxxx part with your own image ID.

**Edit**

This solution does not work when you use the copy functionality provided by AWS.
My new solution is based upon the fact that an EBS volume is added to the ami as a blockingdevice and has access to the snapshot id!
Some code as illustration:

```
/**
 * Removes an ami and its snapshot.
 * @param amiID
 * @param snapshotID
 */
public static void removeImage(final String amiID, final AmazonEC2 ec2) {
    if (amiID != null) {
        DescribeImagesResult result = ec2.describeImages(new DescribeImagesRequest().withImageIds(amiID).withOwners(owner));
        if (!result.getImages().isEmpty()) {
            ec2.deregisterImage(new DeregisterImageRequest(amiID));
            for (BlockDeviceMapping blockingDevice : result.getImages().get(0).getBlockDeviceMappings()) {
                if (blockingDevice.getEbs() != null) {
                    ec2.deleteSnapshot(new DeleteSnapshotRequest().withSnapshotId(blockingDevice.getEbs().getSnapshotId()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```